# SQL Server SSIS package suddenly throws conversion error (csv) ONLY when running in job - works fine running the package manually and on test server

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssms, sql-server-agent

This is a new problem that began about three weeks ago on several jobs that have been running for years without problems - with both SSIS Flat File Sources and script tasks. The error occurs on READ and never makes it to write.

The files are semicolon separated .csv files, and the columns that are throwing the error are decimal values. Since the locale is Danish, that means the decimal character is a comma.

The job in SSMS only points to the SSIS package, which consists of only a data flow task, which contains a Flat File Source and an OLE DB Destination. The job fails before it can get to the destination, throwing the error: "Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column 'Pris' returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potental loss of data""

The package runs without error manually from within VS 2019 using the latest SSIS extension. The errors come when running the package from a SQL Server Agent job.

My first instinct was to change the column properties on the flat file connection manager. It *was* DT_NUMERIC with a precision of 9 and scale of 4 (the destination is numeric(9,4). I changed it to DT_R4 instead (float) and... well that fixed it.

It's not THE fix though. I mean, it works for this particular file, but what about all the others? We have a LOT of them, and even though I *could* modify the packages for all of them, something bothers me about the fact that these jobs were running just fine for years...

I haven't found anything that might have triggered the change. On the day the problems started the Service Account user was added to the local administrator group on another of our machines in order to be able to run a PS script on that machine. SSMS 18 was also installed on the server that day. Other than that, pretty uneventful.

The job is run as the SQL Server Agent Service Account. It runs 99% of our jobs, this is the only type I can see that it acts strange with.

I've checked the locale on the server, the file, the package, everything seems to be matching.
We have a parallel test server. Putting .csv files in the corresponding folders and running the jobs works fine. It's something either with the SQL Server or the Service Account.

I've just been fighting with this so much I can't see straight. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on and point me in the right direction so I can get this fixed?

Comment: What is the default language of the `LOGIN` that the SQL Agent uses?

Comment: @Larnu DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]